# How to put custom url in angularjs $resource?

Tags: angularjs-resource, spring-restcontroller

This is my angularjs service:

```
app.service("ConfigurationMasterService", function($resource){

return $resource('/configurationMasters/crud/:id',{
    id: '@id'
},{
    saveConfig : {
        action : 'saveConfig',
        method : 'GET',
        URL : 'configurationMasters/crud/test',
    }
});


});
```

Angular js controller as follows,

```
    ConfigurationMasterService.saveConfig().$promise.then(function(response){
    alert(response);
}, function(reason) {
    alert(reason);
});
```

Here, i  call the saveConfig() action.

My Rest Controller :

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "configurationMasters/crud/test", method =  RequestMethod.GET )
public void getString(){
    System.out.println("test Method");
    //return "Welcome Custom Method!";
}
```

"saveConfig" is my custom action ,but it is not works while calling this custom action. the error message throwing while try to call the saveConfig action